# How to match a singular value between two data frames when these data frames are not of equal length?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a specific value x (unique) that is contained in df1. I want to match this value x (unique) with the value x (unique) contained in df2 so to obtain the correspondent value "date". The problem is that df1 and df2 have two different row lengths, thus the following function won't work:

`match(df1$x,df2$x)`

`df2$date[match(df1$x,df2$x)]`

`df1$date = df2$date[match(df1$x,df2$x)]`

Example df1 and df2:

df1-->

---

```
    x | y | a | b |
    1   2   6   9
    2   2   7   2
    3   4   8   1 
    4   5   7   2
```

df2-->

---

```
   x | z | date | l | m |
   1   2   1987   a   c
   2   2   1989   b   c 
   3   2   1986   a   d
```

Example final result: 
df1 -->

---

```
    x | y | date 
    1   2   1987 
    2   2   1989
    3   2   1986
```

Comment: A way to solve this is given by this function (credits to a co-worker): 
df1 <- merge(df1, df2, by="x")
However, I get also a bunch of unrelated data that I did not really ask for(since the data frames have more columns than that).

Comment: check edited answer, you need ```dplyr::inner_join```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like `df1$date[df1$date %in% df2$date]` work?

**EDITED after comment**

I see. Now I got it.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = rep(c(2,4), each=2))
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, z = c(2,2,2), date = 1986:1988)

inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("x")) %>% 
  select(-z)
#>   x y date
#> 1 1 2 1986
#> 2 2 2 1987
#> 3 3 4 1988
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Nope: R reports me this --> integer(0)

Comment: It works, I do have a lot of extra info because there are more columns than the one mentioned. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @MatteoTraversini you just need to pull the columns you want. You can do that before or after the join. Doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Yes use ```select(x,y, date)```